# how to save a pandas DataFrame to an excel file?

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to load data from the web source and save it as a Excel file but not sure how to do it. What should I do?

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
import xmltodict


url = "https://www.kstan.ua/sitemap.xml"
res = requests.get(url)
raw = xmltodict.parse(res.text)

data = [[r["loc"], r["lastmod"]] for r in raw["urlset"]["url"]]
print("Number of sitemaps:", len(data))
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=["links", "lastmod"])
```

Comment: Assuming that you don't have the any issues with reading in the XML all you have to do is: `df.to_excel('out.xlsx')` to learn more about `DataFrame.to_excel` go to:    to learn more about I/O for pandas dataframes visit: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_excel.html#pandas.DataFrame.to_excel https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/frame.html#serialization-io-conversion

Answer (score 30):

```
df.to_csv("output.csv", index=False)
```

OR

```
df.to_excel("output.xlsx")
```

Answer (score 4):

You can write the dataframe to excel using the pandas [ExcelWriter](http://pandas-docs.github.io/pandas-docs-travis/reference/api/pandas.ExcelWriter.html), such as this:

```
import pandas as pd
with pd.ExcelWriter('path_to_file.xlsx') as writer:
    dataframe.to_excel(writer)
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to create multiple sheets in the same file

```
with pd.ExcelWriter('csv_s/results.xlsx') as writer:
   same_res.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='same')
   diff_res.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='sheet2')
```