# How to save Pandas info() function output to variable or data frame

Tags: python, pandas

How to save Pandas `df.info()` function output to variable or data frame?
I tried using buffer value but it is not saving output neatly.

Code:

```
import io
buffer = io.StringIO()
df.info(buf=buffer)
s = buffer.getvalue()
with open("df_info.txt", "w",
          encoding="utf-8") as f:  
    f.write(s)
```

Result:

[image]

Sample output:

```
column        non-null count dtype
```

We should get the output like in result in above 3 columns.

How can I do this?

Comment: From the variable name `df` I am inferring you're asking about the `.info()` method of `pandas` dataframes? This function is specifically intended to print information to the console, but all the information it provides can be access directly on the dataframe with other methods and attributes - what exactly do you need from this block that makes you want to capture it?

Comment: Also, the solution you found would be the best solution to do it (except that you want to get the value after writing) - you say it's not formatted neatly, but it's literally writing the output to the text file, so there's no neater way to get it. Do you realise that the console uses a fixed width font instead of a proportional font like Excel does? Have you tried looking at the output in Notepad or another text editor? What exactly is not neat about it in that setting?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to save a pandas DataFrame to an excel file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55170300/how-to-save-a-pandas-dataframe-to-an-excel-file)

Comment: @mkrieger1 that would save the dataframe's *contents* to an Excel file, OP appears to be asking how to get the dataframe's *metadata* into Excel (which will come down to fixed-width parsing of the text output, most likely - unless they just directly access the metadata and write it to a .csv)

Comment: Oh, I mistook the "table" as the dataframe contents.

Comment: i have multiple data frames .I want to save the all the dataframes info() output one after the other. It is not possible to write the output to df with only columns, non-null,dtypes?

Comment: What would "neat" output look like? Can you make a sample dataframe and some sample output?

Comment: @HenryEcker, Neat output would be getting only column , non-null count, dtype only. I am attaching the sample output above

Comment: attached the sample output

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `splitlines` for lists, then indexig for remove first 5 values and last 2 and split by space with DataFrame constructor:

```
import io
buffer = io.StringIO()
df.info(buf=buffer)
lines = buffer.getvalue().splitlines()
df = (pd.DataFrame([x.split() for x in lines[5:-2]], columns=lines[3].split())
       .drop('Count',axis=1)
       .rename(columns={'Non-Null':'Non-Null Count'}))
print (df)
```

Comment: Awesome, it worked. thank you

Comment: This changes types:      df = df.astype({"Non-Null Count": int, "#": int})