# Pdf form into excel

Tags: python

Helloo

I have this pdf file which is basically a form and i want to extract all the field names as a column name and information associated with it and then save it into an excel file.

Please assist me with this how it is possible.

Thank you in advance.

[snapshot of pdf](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lYhT4.png)

Comment: What did you do and what did you give up on?

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [pdfplumber](https://pypi.org/project/pdfplumber/) package. There is a crop function that allows you to specify a bounding box from which you can define areas to extract from. There are a whole list of other functions which are useful for extracting text and form fields etc. For example:
https://github.com/jsvine/pdfplumber#extracting-form-values

This in combination with some **[regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4736/learning-regular-expressions)** selection and matching is often useful. However, I would advise that you give it a go. It is actually not as difficult as you would expect.

Example extracting text from PDF:

```py
with pdfplumber.open(pdf_file) as pdf:
    first_page = pdf.pages[0]
    rows = first_page.extract_text().split('\n')
```

You can then put the data into a **[dataframe](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/dsintro.html#dataframe)** using the [pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/) package, and once it is in this format, it is trivial to [send it to excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55170300/how-to-save-a-pandas-dataframe-to-an-excel-file).

---

## EDIT:

Based on new information, it looks like you are dealing with an **XFA based PDF**. And from my initial attempts was not able to use pdfplumber as described above. My suggestion is to use [PyPDF2](https://pypdf2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/installation.html).

Extract the XML from the PDF document, and then use that to get the information you need. I would say that REGEX would still be an appropriate method here.

**Code to extract the XML from the XFA based PDF:**

```py
import PyPDF2 as pypdf

def findInDict(needle, haystack):
    for key in haystack.keys():
        try:
            value=haystack[key]
        except:
            continue
        if key==needle:
            return value
        if isinstance(value,dict):            
            x=findInDict(needle,value)            
            if x is not None:
                return x

pdfobject=open('Form CHG-1-010216.pdf','rb')
pdf=pypdf.PdfFileReader(pdfobject)
xfa=findInDict('/XFA',pdf.resolved_objects)
xml=xfa[7].getObject().getData()

print(xml)
```

([code source](https://towardsdatascience.com/how-to-extract-data-from-pdf-forms-using-python-10b5e5f26f70))

**Here is the XML extracted from the datasets section of the PDF:**

```
b'\n<xfa:datasets xmlns:xfa="http://www.xfa.org/schema/xfa-data/1.0/"\n><dd:dataDescription xmlns:dd="http://ns.adobe.com/data-description/" dd:name="Form8_Dtls"\n><frm:Form8_Dtls xmlns:frm="http://www.mit.gov.in/eGov/BackOffice/schema/Form"\n><frm:Form8\n><frm:CIN dd:minOccur="0" dd:nullType="exclude"\n/><frm:GLN dd:minOccur="0" dd:nullType="exclude"\n/><frm:EmailID dd:minOccur="0" dd:nullType="exclude"\n/><frm:ChargeType dd:minOccur="0" dd:nullType="exclude"\n/><frm:Applicant dd:minOccur="0" dd:nullType="exclude"\n/><frm:SrnForForm dd:minOccur="0" dd:nullType="exclude"\n/><frm:ChargeID 
dd:minOccur="0" dd:nullType="exclude"\n/><frm:SrnForForm2.28 dd:minOccur="0" dd:nullType="exclude"\n/><frm:Beyond30Within300 dd:minOccur="0" dd:nullType="exclude"\n/><frm:Beyond300 dd:minOccur="0" dd:nullType="exclude"\n/><frm:ReasonDelay dd:minOccur="0" 
dd:nullType="exclude"\n/><frm:WhthrChrgARCorAssignd dd:minOccur="0" dd:nullType="exclude"\n/><frm:WhthrChrghldrAuth dd:minOccur="0" dd:nullType="exclude"\n/><frm:UnCldShrCptl dd:minOccur="0" dd:nullType="exclude"\n/><frm:Improperty dd:minOccur="0" dd:nullType="exclude"\n/><frm:AnyIntrstImproperty dd:minOccur="0" dd:nullType="exclude"\n/><frm:BookDebts dd:minOccur="0" dd:nullType="exclude"\n/><frm:MovProperty dd:minOccur="0" dd:nullType="exclude"\n/><frm:FloatngChrg dd:minOccur="0" dd:nullType="exclude"\n/><frm:CallsMadeNotPaid dd:minOccur="0" dd:nullType="exclude"\n/><frm:Ship dd:minOccur="0" dd:nullType="exclude"\n/><frm:Goodwill dd:minOccur="0" dd:nullType="exclude"\n/><frm:PatentLicence dd:minOccur="0" dd:nullType="exclude"\n/><frm:tradeMark dd:minOccur="0" dd:nullType="exclude"\n/><frm:Copyright dd:minOccur="0" dd:nullType="exclude"\n/><frm:Others dd:minOccur="0" dd:nullType="exclude"\n/><frm:OthersSpec dd:minOccur="0" dd:nullType="exclude"\n/><frm:ConsrtmInvld dd:minOccur="0" dd:nullType="exclude"\n/><frm:JointChrgInvld dd:minOccur="0" dd:nullType="exclude"\n/><frm:NoOfChargeHolders 
dd:minOccur="0" dd:nullType="exclude"\n/><frm:CategoryBank dd:minOccur="0" dd:nullType="exclude"\n/><frm:IfCategoryOthers dd:minOccur="0" dd:nullType="exclude"\n/><frm:ChargeHolderDetails dd:minOccur="0"\n><cdt:Cin xmlns:cdt="http://www.mit.gov.in/eGov/BackOffice/schema/ComplexDataTypes" dd:minOccur="0" dd:nullType="exclude"\n/><cdt:ChrgHldrName xmlns:cdt="http://www.mit.gov.in/eGov/BackOffice/schema/ComplexDataTypes" dd:minOccur="0" dd:nullType="exclude"\n/><cdt:OptionalName xmlns:cdt="http://www.mit.gov.in/eGov/BackOffice/schema/ComplexDataTypes" dd:minOccur="0" dd:nullType="exclude"\n/><cdt:ChargeHldrAddress xmlns:cdt="http://www.mit.gov.in/eGov/BackOffice/schema/ComplexDataTypes"\n><cdt:AddressLn\n><cdt:FirstLine\n/><cdt:SecondLine dd:minOccur="0" dd:nullType="exclude"\n/></cdt:AddressLn\n><cdt:City\n/><cdt:State\n/><cdt:Country dd:minOccur="0" dd:nullType="exclude"\n/><cdt:CountryName dd:minOccur="0" dd:nullType="exclude"\n/><cdt:Pincode dd:minOccur="0" dd:nullType="exclude"\n/><cdt:Telephone dd:minOccur="0" dd:nullType="exclude"\n/><cdt:Fax dd:minOccur="0" dd:nullType="exclude"\n/><cdt:Email dd:minOccur="0" dd:nullType="exclude"\n/><cdt:Mbl dd:minOccur="0" dd:nullType="exclude"\n/></cdt:ChargeHldrAddress\n></frm:ChargeHolderDetails\n><frm:InstrumentDesc dd:minOccur="0" dd:nullType="exclude"\n/><frm:InstrumentCrtModDate dd:minOccur="0" dd:nullType="exclude"\n/><frm:WhthrChrgCrMod dd:minOccur="0" dd:nullType="exclude"\n/><frm:FrgnChargeRcptDate dd:minOccur="0" dd:nullType="exclude"\n/><frm:AmtSecured 
dd:minOccur="0" dd:nullType="exclude"\n/><frm:AmtSecChrgInWords dd:minOccur="0" dd:nullType="exclude"\n/><frm:AmtSecChrgFrgnCurrncyDetails dd:minOccur="0" dd:nullType="exclude"\n/><frm:TermsAndConditions dd:minOccur="0"\n><frm:RateOfInt dd:minOccur="0" dd:nullType="exclude"\n/><frm:TermsOfPaymnt dd:minOccur="0" dd:nullType="exclude"\n/><frm:Margin dd:minOccur="0" dd:nullType="exclude"\n/><frm:ExtntOperatnChrg dd:minOccur="0" dd:nullType="exclude"\n/><frm:Others dd:minOccur="0" dd:nullType="exclude"\n/></frm:TermsAndConditions\n><frm:ExstngChrgAcqDtls dd:minOccur="0"\n><frm:InstrDate dd:minOccur="0" dd:nullType="exclude"\n/><frm:InstrDescr dd:minOccur="0" dd:nullType="exclude"\n/><frm:DateofAcq dd:minOccur="0" dd:nullType="exclude"\n/><frm:ChrgAmnt dd:minOccur="0" dd:nullType="exclude"\n/><frm:PropChrgPartclrs dd:minOccur="0" dd:nullType="exclude"\n/></frm:ExstngChrgAcqDtls\n><frm:PropParticlars dd:minOccur="0" dd:nullType="exclude"\n/><frm:NewPropParticlars dd:maxOccur="10" dd:minOccur="0" dd:nullType="exclude"\n/><frm:PropOwnCmp dd:minOccur="0" dd:nullType="exclude"\n/><frm:PropRegisteredName dd:minOccur="0" dd:nullType="exclude"\n/><frm:DateOfLatestMod dd:minOccur="0" dd:nullType="exclude"\n/><frm:PartclrsPresntMod dd:minOccur="0" dd:nullType="exclude"\n/><frm:BoardResNo dd:minOccur="0" dd:nullType="exclude"\n/><frm:AuthSigReslnDt dd:minOccur="0" dd:nullType="exclude"\n/><frm:DesignationOne dd:minOccur="0" dd:nullType="exclude"\n/><frm:DIN dd:minOccur="0" dd:nullType="exclude"\n/><frm:DesignationTwo dd:minOccur="0" dd:nullType="exclude"\n/><frm:DesignationThree dd:minOccur="0" dd:nullType="exclude"\n/><frm:CharteredOrCostOrCompSec dd:minOccur="0" dd:nullType="exclude"\n/><frm:AssociateorFellow dd:minOccur="0" dd:nullType="exclude"\n/><frm:MembershipnumberorCertificate dd:minOccur="0" dd:nullType="exclude"\n/><frm:CertificateNo dd:minOccur="0" dd:nullType="exclude"\n/><frm:strBankName dd:minOccur="0" dd:nullType="exclude"\n/><frm:CondonationFlag dd:minOccur="0" dd:nullType="exclude"\n/><frm:HTF dd:minOccur="0" dd:nullType="exclude"\n/><frm:IPresNumber dd:minOccur="0" dd:nullType="exclude"\n/><frm:FormId dd:minOccur="0" dd:nullType="exclude"\n/><frm:VersionNo dd:minOccur="0" dd:nullType="exclude"\n/><frm:Form_Language dd:minOccur="0" dd:nullType="exclude"\n/><frm:BoPreFilldataForm dd:minOccur="0"\n><cdt:DateOfFiling xmlns:cdt="http://www.mit.gov.in/eGov/BackOffice/schema/ComplexDataTypes"\n/><cdt:DateOfSigning xmlns:cdt="http://www.mit.gov.in/eGov/BackOffice/schema/ComplexDataTypes"\n/><cdt:eFormSRN xmlns:cdt="http://www.mit.gov.in/eGov/BackOffice/schema/ComplexDataTypes"\n/><cdt:MngmtDispute xmlns:cdt="http://www.mit.gov.in/eGov/BackOffice/schema/ComplexDataTypes" dd:minOccur="0" dd:nullType="exclude"\n/></frm:BoPreFilldataForm\n><frm:MngmtDispute dd:minOccur="0" dd:nullType="exclude"\n/><frm:LSI dd:minOccur="0" dd:nullType="exclude"\n/><frm:HostVersion dd:minOccur="0" dd:nullType="exclude"\n/><frm:HostAppName dd:minOccur="0" dd:nullType="exclude"\n/><frm:TotalPageNo dd:minOccur="0" dd:nullType="exclude"\n/><frm:EfmUniqueID dd:minOccur="0" dd:nullType="exclude"\n/><frm:AttachmentNames dd:minOccur="0" dd:nullType="exclude"\n/></frm:Form8\n></frm:Form8_Dtls\n></dd:dataDescription\n><dd:dataDescription xmlns:dd="http://ns.adobe.com/data-description/" dd:name="CINDataConngetCINLLPINDetailsRequestDD"\n><CINDataConn\n><soap:Body xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"\n><impl:getCINLLPINDetails xmlns:impl="http://prefill.eforms.userinterface.mydca.dca21.com"\n><impl:strCINLLPIN dd:nullType="xsi"\n/></impl:getCINLLPINDetails\n></soap:Body\n></CINDataConn\n></dd:dataDescription\n><dd:dataDescription xmlns:dd="http://ns.adobe.com/data-description/" dd:name="CINSplitDataConn1getChrgHolderAddressWitCondRequestDD"\n><CINSplitDataConn1\n><soap:Body xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"\n><impl:getChrgHolderAddressWitCond xmlns:impl="http://prefill.eforms.userinterface.mydca.dca21.com"\n><impl:strCompanyID dd:nullType="xsi"\n/></impl:getChrgHolderAddressWitCond\n></soap:Body\n></CINSplitDataConn1\n></dd:dataDescription\n><dd:dataDescription xmlns:dd="http://ns.adobe.com/data-description/" dd:name="ForeignCmpnyDataConngetForeignCompanyDetailsNewRequestDD"\n><ForeignCmpnyDataConn\n><soap:Body xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"\n><impl:getForeignCompanyDetailsNew xmlns:impl="http://prefill.eforms.userinterface.mydca.dca21.com"\n><impl:strCompanyID dd:nullType="xsi"\n/></impl:getForeignCompanyDetailsNew\n></soap:Body\n></ForeignCmpnyDataConn\n></dd:dataDescription\n><dd:dataDescription xmlns:dd="http://ns.adobe.com/data-description/" dd:name="PrescrutinyServiceserviceForm8RequestDD"\n><PrescrutinyService\n><soap:Body xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"\n><impl:serviceForm8 xmlns:impl="http://prefill.eforms.userinterface.mydca.dca21.com"\n><impl:objForm8PrescDDto dd:nullType="xsi"\n><tns2:DBoardResDate xmlns:tns2="http://dto.eforms.business.mydca.dca21.com" dd:nullType="xsi"\n/><tns2:DDateOfLatestMod xmlns:tns2="http://dto.eforms.business.mydca.dca21.com" dd:nullType="xsi"\n/><tns2:DTempAcqstnDate xmlns:tns2="http://dto.eforms.business.mydca.dca21.com" dd:nullType="xsi"\n/><tns2:extntOperatnChrg xmlns:tns2="http://dto.eforms.business.mydca.dca21.com" dd:nullType="xsi"\n/><tns2:margin xmlns:tns2="http://dto.eforms.business.mydca.dca21.com" dd:nullType="xsi"\n/><tns2:others xmlns:tns2="http://dto.eforms.business.mydca.dca21.com" dd:nullType="xsi"\n/><tns2:partclrsPresntMod xmlns:tns2="http://dto.eforms.business.mydca.dca21.com" dd:nullType="xsi"\n/><tns2:propParticlars xmlns:tns2="http://dto.eforms.business.mydca.dca21.com" dd:nullType="xsi"\n/><tns2:rateOfInt xmlns:tns2="http://dto.eforms.business.mydca.dca21.com" dd:nullType="xsi"\n/><tns2:termsOfPaymnt xmlns:tns2="http://dto.eforms.business.mydca.dca21.com" dd:nullType="xsi"\n/><tns2:whthrChrgCrMod xmlns:tns2="http://dto.eforms.business.mydca.dca21.com" dd:nullType="xsi"\n/><tns2:DInstrCrtEvdDate xmlns:tns2="http://dto.eforms.business.mydca.dca21.com" dd:nullType="xsi"\n/><tns2:DInstrCrtModDate xmlns:tns2="http://dto.eforms.business.mydca.dca21.com" dd:nullType="xsi"\n/><tns2:DTempFrgnCharge xmlns:tns2="http://dto.eforms.business.mydca.dca21.com" dd:nullType="xsi"\n/><tns2:dupFlag xmlns:tns2="http://dto.eforms.business.mydca.dca21.com" dd:nullType="xsi"\n/><tns2:formID xmlns:tns2="http://dto.eforms.business.mydca.dca21.com" dd:nullType="xsi"\n/><tns2:formVersion xmlns:tns2="http://dto.eforms.business.mydca.dca21.com" dd:nullType="xsi"\n/><tns2:presNumber xmlns:tns2="http://dto.eforms.business.mydca.dca21.com" dd:nullType="xsi"\n/><tns2:strChargeType xmlns:tns2="http://dto.eforms.business.mydca.dca21.com" dd:nullType="xsi"\n/><tns2:strChrgCIN xmlns:tns2="http://dto.eforms.business.mydca.dca21.com" dd:nullType="xsi"\n/><tns2:strChrgHldrName xmlns:tns2="http://dto.eforms.business.mydca.dca21.com" dd:nullType="xsi"\n/><tns2:strCIN xmlns:tns2="http://dto.eforms.business.mydca.dca21.com" dd:nullType="xsi"\n/><tns2:strCountryCode xmlns:tns2="http://dto.eforms.business.mydca.dca21.com" dd:nullType="xsi"\n/><tns2:strDesignation xmlns:tns2="http://dto.eforms.business.mydca.dca21.com" dd:nullType="xsi"\n/><tns2:strDINMembrshpNo xmlns:tns2="http://dto.eforms.business.mydca.dca21.com" dd:nullType="xsi"\n/><tns2:strPinCode xmlns:tns2="http://dto.eforms.business.mydca.dca21.com" dd:nullType="xsi"\n/><tns2:strStateCode xmlns:tns2="http://dto.eforms.business.mydca.dca21.com" dd:nullType="xsi"\n/></impl:objForm8PrescDDto\n></impl:serviceForm8\n></soap:Body\n></PrescrutinyService\n></dd:dataDescription\n><xfa:data\n><frm:Form8_Dtls xmlns:frm="http://www.mit.gov.in/eGov/BackOffice/schema/Form"\n><frm:Form8\n><frm:CIN\n>U37100DL2004PTC128960</frm:CIN\n><frm:EmailID\n>vwcpl@yahoo.com</frm:EmailID\n><frm:ChargeType\n>CRTN</frm:ChargeType\n><frm:Applicant\n>Company</frm:Applicant\n><frm:Beyond30Within300\n>Yes</frm:Beyond30Within300\n><frm:ReasonDelay\n>Due to some DSC problems</frm:ReasonDelay\n><frm:UnCldShrCptl\n>2ONE</frm:UnCldShrCptl\n><frm:Improperty\n>2MMP</frm:Improperty\n><frm:AnyIntrstImproperty\n>2ONE</frm:AnyIntrstImproperty\n><frm:BookDebts\n>2ONE</frm:BookDebts\n><frm:MovProperty\n>2OVP</frm:MovProperty\n><frm:FloatngChrg\n>2ONE</frm:FloatngChrg\n><frm:CallsMadeNotPaid\n>2ONE</frm:CallsMadeNotPaid\n><frm:Ship\n>2ONE</frm:Ship\n><frm:Goodwill\n>2ONE</frm:Goodwill\n><frm:PatentLicence\n>2ONE</frm:PatentLicence\n><frm:tradeMark\n>2ONE</frm:tradeMark\n><frm:Copyright\n>2ONE</frm:Copyright\n><frm:Others\n>2THS</frm:Others\n><frm:OthersSpec\n>movable / immovable fixed assets</frm:OthersSpec\n><frm:ConsrtmInvld\n>NO</frm:ConsrtmInvld\n><frm:JointChrgInvld\n>NO</frm:JointChrgInvld\n><frm:NoOfChargeHolders\n>1</frm:NoOfChargeHolders\n><frm:CategoryBank\n>NATB</frm:CategoryBank\n><frm:ChargeHolderDetails\n><cdt:ChrgHldrName xmlns:cdt="http://www.mit.gov.in/eGov/BackOffice/schema/ComplexDataTypes"\n>Others</cdt:ChrgHldrName\n><cdt:OptionalName xmlns:cdt="http://www.mit.gov.in/eGov/BackOffice/schema/ComplexDataTypes"\n>State Bank of Patiala</cdt:OptionalName\n><cdt:ChargeHldrAddress xmlns:cdt="http://www.mit.gov.in/eGov/BackOffice/schema/ComplexDataTypes"\n><cdt:AddressLn\n><cdt:FirstLine\n>MCG Pitampura</cdt:FirstLine\n><cdt:SecondLine\n>A-102, D-Mall, Netaji Subash Place</cdt:SecondLine\n></cdt:AddressLn\n><cdt:City\n>Delhi</cdt:City\n><cdt:State\n>DL</cdt:State\n><cdt:Country\n>IN</cdt:Country\n><cdt:CountryName\n>INDIA</cdt:CountryName\n><cdt:Pincode\n>110034</cdt:Pincode\n><cdt:Email\n>nimishdel@gmail.com</cdt:Email\n></cdt:ChargeHldrAddress\n></frm:ChargeHolderDetails\n><frm:InstrumentDesc\n>Agreement of Loan Cum Hypothecation&#xD;Letter of Arrangement&#xD;Agreement of Mortgage</frm:InstrumentDesc\n><frm:InstrumentCrtModDate\n>2015-12-30</frm:InstrumentCrtModDate\n><frm:WhthrChrgCrMod\n>NO</frm:WhthrChrgCrMod\n><frm:AmtSecured\n>6000000.00</frm:AmtSecured\n><frm:AmtSecChrgInWords\n>Rupees Sixty Lacs  only</frm:AmtSecChrgInWords\n><frm:TermsAndConditions\n><frm:RateOfInt\n>Term Loan of Rs.60.00 Lakh - @ 3.10 % above base rate, present 
effective rate 12.75 % p. a. with monthly rests.</frm:RateOfInt\n><frm:TermsOfPaymnt\n>The Term Loan of Rs.60.00 Lakh shall be repayable in 26 quarterly installments of Rs.2,25,000/- each, commencing from June, 2016 (last installment of Rs.4,00,000/- )</frm:TermsOfPaymnt\n><frm:Margin\n>41.19 %</frm:Margin\n><frm:ExtntOperatnChrg\n>100 percent.</frm:ExtntOperatnChrg\n><frm:Others\n>THE ABOVE IS TO SECURE THE FOLLOWING CREDIT FACILITIES GRANTED TO THE COMPANY :-&#xD;1. Term Loan             - Rs.60.00 Lakh</frm:Others\n></frm:TermsAndConditions\n><frm:Form_Language\n>ENGL</frm:Form_Language\n><frm:BoPreFilldataForm\n><cdt:DateOfFiling xmlns:cdt="http://www.mit.gov.in/eGov/BackOffice/schema/ComplexDataTypes"\n/><cdt:DateOfSigning xmlns:cdt="http://www.mit.gov.in/eGov/BackOffice/schema/ComplexDataTypes"\n/><cdt:eFormSRN xmlns:cdt="http://www.mit.gov.in/eGov/BackOffice/schema/ComplexDataTypes"\n/></frm:BoPreFilldataForm\n><frm:HostVersion\n>22.00220191</frm:HostVersion\n><frm:HostAppName\n>Reader</frm:HostAppName\n><frm:TotalPageNo\n>6</frm:TotalPageNo\n><frm:EfmUniqueID\n>Form89JOK7KCC3A8WGXDDT7VVA3ZKNRG</frm:EfmUniqueID\n><frm:LSI\n>1</frm:LSI\n><frm:ExstngChrgAcqDtls\n/><frm:NewPropParticlars\n>Hypothecation of all movable / immovable fixed assets of the company created out of the Term Loan.</frm:NewPropParticlars\n><frm:NewPropParticlars\n>Equitable mortgage of Shop No. CSC - 39, DDA Market, A Block, Saraswati Vihar, Delhi -110 034.</frm:NewPropParticlars\n><frm:PropOwnCmp\n>NO</frm:PropOwnCmp\n><frm:BoardResNo\n>03</frm:BoardResNo\n><frm:AuthSigReslnDt\n>2015-12-14</frm:AuthSigReslnDt\n><frm:DesignationOne\n>DIRT</frm:DesignationOne\n><frm:DIN\n>05153044</frm:DIN\n><frm:DesignationTwo\n>AACCS0143D</frm:DesignationTwo\n><frm:CharteredOrCostOrCompSec\n>CA</frm:CharteredOrCostOrCompSec\n><frm:AssociateorFellow\n>FW</frm:AssociateorFellow\n><frm:MembershipnumberorCertificate\n>508508</frm:MembershipnumberorCertificate\n><frm:CertificateNo\n>508508</frm:CertificateNo\n><frm:AttachmentNames\n>2014.pdf,2900.pdf</frm:AttachmentNames\n><frm:HTF\n>NO</frm:HTF\n><frm:IPresNumber\n>0</frm:IPresNumber\n><frm:FormId\n>Form8</frm:FormId\n><frm:VersionNo\n>30</frm:VersionNo\n></frm:Form8\n><CompanyName_C\n>VEERA WASIR CONSULTANTS PRIVATE LIMITED</CompanyName_C\n><ExtractedVersion\n>30</ExtractedVersion\n><Hidden_FormLanguage\n/><CompanyAdd_C\n>9 CSC DDA MARKETA-BLOCK\nSARASWATI VIHAR\nDELHI\nDelhi\nINDIA\n110085</CompanyAdd_C\n><hiddenEmailID\n/><Hidden_L\n>Agreement of Hyp.pdf:2014:Agreement of Mortgage.pdf:2900</Hidden_L\n><Err_C\n/><isDupFlag\n>NO</isDupFlag\n><PrescruitnyErr_N\n>-1</PrescruitnyErr_N\n><BOFiling_errMsg\n/><BOFilingFlag\n>NO</BOFilingFlag\n><CheckForm_C\n>NO</CheckForm_C\n></frm:Form8_Dtls\n></xfa:data\n><dd:dataDescription xmlns:dd="http://ns.adobe.com/data-description/" dd:name="ChargeHoldersDataConngetBankDetailsRequestDD"\n><ChargeHoldersDataConn\n><soap:Body xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"\n><impl:getBankDetails xmlns:impl="http://prefill.eforms.userinterface.mydca.dca21.com"\n><impl:strFormId dd:nullType="xsi"\n/></impl:getBankDetails\n></soap:Body\n></ChargeHoldersDataConn\n></dd:dataDescription\n><dd:dataDescription xmlns:dd="http://ns.adobe.com/data-description/" dd:name="GetBOFilingDtlsgetFilingDtlsRequestDD"\n><GetBOFilingDtls\n><soap:Body xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"\n><impl:getFilingDtls xmlns:impl="http://common.userinterface.backoffice.dca21.com"\n><eFilingInDDto dd:nullType="xsi"\n><formId dd:nullType="xsi"\n/><formUniqueId dd:nullType="xsi"\n/></eFilingInDDto\n></impl:getFilingDtls\n></soap:Body\n></GetBOFilingDtls\n></dd:dataDescription\n><dd:dataDescription xmlns:dd="http://ns.adobe.com/data-description/" dd:name="NewCINDataConngetCINLLPINDetails_SCRequestDD"\n><NewCINDataConn\n><soap:Body xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"\n><impl:getCINLLPINDetails_SC xmlns:impl="http://prefill.eforms.userinterface.mydca.dca21.com"\n><impl:strCINLLPIN\n/></impl:getCINLLPINDetails_SC\n></soap:Body\n></NewCINDataConn\n></dd:dataDescription\n></xfa:datasets\n>'
```

You can also extract from the form section:

```py
xml2=xfa[13].getObject().getData()

print(xml2)
```

Comment: I've tried using this, but for some reason, the PDF won't load. Can you help me with this? I'm new to this. How can I send the PDF file to you?

Comment: Maybe upload here: https://send.internxt.com/  and then post the link.

Comment: https://send.internxt.com/download/8c31a3e5-6a26-40d3-967a-5471a91157ca?code=59b3a8e45df62163a874d3dead3ee83e4e40a7720f597a949ec6f19832121c20

Comment: now how to convert this into pandas dataframe?

Comment: I think first we have to convert it into pandas dataframe then only we can save it into excel

Comment: Is your plan just to dump it into excel ? Or do you plan to process it first ?

Comment: dump it into excel with all field and values associated with it

Comment: That will take some effort. But I will leave that to you :)
You have an output in bytes - you can convert that to string with `xml.decode("utf-8")`. Then you have the fun of extracting the info you need. If you split by a specific character, you will end up with a list. And then it is simple to convert a list to a dataframe.

Comment: ook sure il try :)

Comment: With the above code...all fields are not coming

Comment: If it is not getting all fields , then I am out of options. Sorry.

Comment: Hey hiee...can you tell me how to convert JSON to CSV..?