# Python export to Excel file issues

Tags: python, excel, export-to-excel

I'm using an API to pull data from a website and then save it as an excel file on my computer using Python. I then use another software (Eviews) to analyze the data in the newly generated Excel file. When I try to access the excel file using Eviews, I get an error:

```
"File 'C:\Users\OLEVIA~1.SHA\AppData\ev_temp\evxlsx1\xl//xl
/worksheets/sheet1.xml' does not exist in "IMPORT R:\FORECASTING\CHR\DATA\MORTGAGERATES_TEST.XLSX
 @FREQ M 1971:4" on line 10".
```

When I go into the file using excel and save it (without changing anything at all), `Eviews` is then able to see that it exists, so I know it isn't necessarily an issue on the `Eviews` side, but rather the way Python is saving the file to my computer. Currently this is the code I'm using:

```
os.chdir('R:\Forecasting\CHR\Data')
IRFHLMCFM_IUSA.to_excel("MortgageRates_TEST.xlsx", sheet_name='30YrMrtgRt', index=False)
```

Is there another way to save the dataframe to my computer as an excel file that I could try?

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55170300/how-to-save-a-pandas-dataframe-to-an-excel-file

Answer (score 0):

Did you activate your venv, and install the required package

And the other reason could be that your folder is a simple forlder which it has to be a python package which is contained **init**.py file as a way that python can import other files into eachother

Comment: I have imported all of the packages I should need. To clarify, the python code mentioned above is creating an excel file in the specified directory, it just isn't accessible by the other  software (Eviews) without going into the file and saving it first.